# PHP: In shopping cart, Fatal error: Call to undefined function getCart()

Tags: php, function, session, shopping-cart

Recently I start with php and not because it gives me this error.
This code is onyl for show articles and total price of shopping cart when reload page, using PHPSESSID, if they have a better idea or an alternative for that function, they are appreciated!

**INDEX.PHP**

```
<?php require("php/DB_Functionss.php"); ?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    ........
</head>
<body>
    <div id="infoShopCart">
       <a href="contShopping"><img src="img/shopping_cart.png" width="30px"/>
       Artículos: <b id="cantArticles">0</b>
       Total: $ <b id="totalPriceArticles">0.00</b></a>
       <?php getCart(); ?>
    </div>
.....
....
</body>
</html>
```

AND **DB_Functions.php**

```
session_start();
$sessionID = $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'];

    class DB_Functions {

        private $db;
        //put your code here
        //constructor
        function __construct() {
            require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
            //connecting to database
            $this->db = new DB_Connect();
            $this->db->connect();
        }
        //destructor
        function __destruct() {

        }
      public function getCart(){
            $query ="SELECT * FROM carrito ORDER BY id_pelicula";
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

            $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
            if($no_of_rows > 0) {
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $totalItems     = $totalItems + 1;
                    $movieTotalPrice    = $movieTotalPrice + $row['precio_pelicula'];
                }
                echo ("Artículos: <b id='cantArticles'>"+$totalItems+"</b><otal: $ <b id='totalPriceArticles'>"+$totalPrice+"</b></a>");
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: And what exactly is not clear from the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize the object and then use its method. Like so:

```
<div id="infoShopCart">
   <a href="contShopping"><img src="img/shopping_cart.png" width="30px"/>
   Artículos: <b id="cantArticles">0</b>
   Total: $ <b id="totalPriceArticles">0.00</b></a>
   <?php
       $db_object = new DB_Functions();
       $db_object->getCart();
   ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked for me! But, now my problem is that not print totalItems and totalPrince in div :/, i.e, print totalItems bot out of div!

Answer (score 1):

Create an **instance** of `DB_Functions` first:

```
$dbf = new DB_Functions;
$dbf->getCart();
```

Comment: Don't you need '()' after DB_Functions ?

Comment: it's optional, need only if you have params to pass

Comment: Worked for me but ur andswer its the same that @Gustav :/

Comment: @SoldierCorp: Because that was obvious issue and yes my answer is same  and his answer is also same as mine and there is nothing hard to figure it out or copy each other :)

Answer (score 0):

You have spelt DB_Functions with two ss's:

> require("php/DB_Functionss.php");

Comment: He might have named the file that way probably

Answer (score 0):

You can encounter that problem with the help of some CSS or Jquery addons.. I supposes.. and also increase the width more..
Yours is 38px only I suppose or else you can use

```
$('div').getWidth()+some number;
```

in jquery

Answer (score 0):

Apart from not instantiating the object as other answers have said, you have problems here:

```
echo ("Artículos: <b id='cantArticles'>"+$totalItems+"</b><otal: $ <b id='totalPriceArticles'>"+$totalPrice+"</b></a>");
```

This is wrong: `</b><otal:`

Also you are closing an `</a>` here but you never opened one to begin with.

Fixed:

```
echo ("Artículos: <b id='cantArticles'>"+$totalItems+"</b>Total: $ <b id='totalPriceArticles'>"+$totalPrice+"</b>");
```

Additionally, there is a better way to obtain the current session id instead of trying to read the raw cookie:

```
$sessionID = session_id();
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you don't need define class, you can do something that Gustav mentioned. (you must first *initiate an object* and then call the method)

I think it is better that you use out of class **function**, or using **static method**, instead.

```
session_start();
$sessionID = $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'];

    class DB_Functions {

        private $db;
        //put your code here
        //constructor
        static function initDb() {
            require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
            //connecting to database
            $this->db = new DB_Connect();
            $this->db->connect();
        }
      public static function getCart(){
            $query ="SELECT * FROM carrito ORDER BY id_pelicula";
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

            $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
            if($no_of_rows > 0) {
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $totalItems     = $totalItems + 1;
                    $movieTotalPrice    = $movieTotalPrice + $row['precio_pelicula'];
                }
                echo ("Artículos: <b id='cantArticles'>"+$totalItems+"</b><otal: $ <b id='totalPriceArticles'>"+$totalPrice+"</b></a>");
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

or using without declaring them in class

```
session_start();
$sessionID = $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'];

        //put your code here
        function initDb() {
            require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
            //connecting to database
            $db = new DB_Connect();
            $db->connect();
        }
            function getCart(){
            $query ="SELECT * FROM carrito ORDER BY id_pelicula";
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

            $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
            if($no_of_rows > 0) {
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $totalItems     = $totalItems + 1;
                    $movieTotalPrice    = $movieTotalPrice + $row['precio_pelicula'];
                }
                echo ("Artículos: <b id='cantArticles'>"+$totalItems+"</b><otal: $ <b id='totalPriceArticles'>"+$totalPrice+"</b></a>");
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```